# How can I improve my C++ code?

Tags: c++

This is my first program I really created besides hello world. The code is over 400 lines of code and wanted to know of new functions and what not that would help improve my code and my knowledge of C++. I figured I would just dive in and learn on my own instead of out of the book I have "Teach yourself C++ in one hour a day 6th edition".

What are some new functions I can learn that would improve my code?

```
// Runescape Mining Calculator

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int lvl;
    int exp;
    int result;

    cout << " \t\t\tRunescape Skill Calculator" << endl;
    cout << " Enter Target level: ";
    cin>>lvl;

    switch(lvl)
    {
                    case 2: cout << " What is your current experience? ";;
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=83 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 3: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=174 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 4: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=276 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 5: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=388 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 6: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=512 - exp;
                        break;                  
                    case 7: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=650 - exp;
                    break;                  
                    case 8: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=801 - exp;
                    break;                  
                    case 9: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=969 - exp;
                    break;                  
                    case 10: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=1154 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 11: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=1358 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 12: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=1584 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 13: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=1833 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 14: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=2107 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 15: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=2411 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 16: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=2746 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 17: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=3115 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 18: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=3523 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 19: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=3973 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 20: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=4470 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 21: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=5018 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 22: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=5624 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 23: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=6291 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 24: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=7028 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 25: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=7842 - exp;
                    break;
                        case 26: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=8740 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 27: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=9730 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 28: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=10824 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 29: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=12031 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 30: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=13363 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 31: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=14833 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 32: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=16456 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 33: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=18247 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 34: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=20224 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 35: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=22406 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 36: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=24815 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 37: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=27473 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 38: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=30408 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 39: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=33648 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 40: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=37224 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 41: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=41171 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 42: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=45529 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 43: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=50339- exp;
                        break;
                    case 44: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=55649 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 45: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=61512 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 46: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=67983 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 47: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=75127 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 48: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=83014 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 49: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=91721 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 50: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=101333 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 51: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=111945 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 52: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=123660 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 53: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=136594 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 54: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=150872 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 55: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=166636 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 56: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=184040 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 57: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=203254 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 58: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=224466 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 59: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=247886 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 60: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=273742 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 61: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=302288 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 62: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=333804 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 63: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=368599 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 64: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=407015 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 65: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=449428 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 66: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=496254 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 67: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=547953 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 68: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=605032 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 69: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=668051 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 70: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=737627 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 71: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=814445 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 72: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=899257 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 73: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=992895 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 74: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=1096278 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 75: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=1210421 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 76: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=1336443 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 77: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=1475581 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 78: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=1629200 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 79: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=1798808 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 80: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=1986068 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 81: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=2192818 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 82: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=2421087 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 83: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=2673114 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 84: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=2951373 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 85: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=3258594 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 86: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=3597792 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 87: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=3972294 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 88: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=4385776 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 89: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=4842295 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 90: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=5346332 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 91: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=5902831 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 92: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=6517253 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 93: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=7195629 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 94: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=7944614 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 95: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=8771558 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 96: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=9684577 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 97: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=10692629 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 98: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=11805606 - exp;
                    break;
                    case 99: cout << " What is your current experience? ";
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=13034431 - exp;
                    case 100: cout << " What is your current experience? " <<endl;
                    cin >> exp;
                    result=14391160 - exp;
                    break;
                    default: exit(0);
                    }
                    cout << " Experience Needed: " << result  << endl;
// Ores needed to be mined to acquire the level up.
                    cout << " Rune Essence: " << ceil(result/5.0) << endl;
                    cout << " Clay: " << ceil(result/5.0) << endl;
                    cout << " Copper: " << ceil(result/17.5) << endl;
                    cout << " Tin: " << ceil(result/17.5) << endl;
                    cout << " Bluerite: " << ceil(result/17.5) << endl;
                    cout << " Iron: " << ceil(result/35.0) << endl;
                    cout << " Silver: " << ceil(result/40.0) << endl;
                    cout << " Coal: " << ceil(result/50.0) << endl;
                    cout << " Gold: " << ceil(result/65.0) << endl;
                    cout << " Mithril: " << ceil(result/80.0) << endl;
                    cout << " Adamant: " << ceil(result/ 95.0) << endl;
                    cout << " Runite: " << ceil(result/125.0) << endl;
                    cout << endl << endl << endl << "\t\t\tCreated by USDblades" << endl;
         return 0;
}
```

Edit: Sorry was not clear. I am trying to improve the code for the Runescape Skill Calculator I am working on. I am curious if I could have cut out some lines of code by using different functions. The Code provided is my project I am working on. Can you review it and give me pointers?

Comment: For one thing, your code is ridiculously redundant (the same `cout` and `cin` lines are repeated about 100x each). You also just throw out a lot of magic numbers. I was about to post an answer but Mike DiSimone got to it first.

Comment: "DeSimone."  And who is Alex?  The guy from TDWTF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `switch` statement is unnecessary.  Since

```
cout << " What is your current experience? ";
cin >> exp;
```

is exactly the same code in all cases, you can move it out of the `switch` (to right before it).  Before those lines, add code which checks that `lvl` is in the range from 2 to 100 and exits.  Then you'll see that all the cases remaining are of the form

```
result = k - exp;
```

where `k` is some integer.  Create an array with 101 elements (so the indices go from 0 to 100) to hold all the possible values of `k`, and initialize it:

```
unsigned expToNextLevel[101] = {
    0, 0, 83, 174, 276, /* and so on */
};
```

Then your huge `switch` statement turns into:

```
if(lvl < 2 || lvl > 100)
    exit(0);

cout << " What is your current experience? ";
cin >> exp;
result = expToNextLevel[lvl] - exp;
```

You can use a similar technique of moving things into arrays to take your block of `cout` lines listing each material and ore requirements and turn it into a `for` loop.

One of the fundamental skills of programming is to recognize repetition and find a way to turn it into a loop or otherwise simplify it.  What you've written is called "spaghetti code", and a red flag is that there's a lot of copying and pasting.

Whenever you find yourself copying and pasting code, you should think "this should be a loop or a function." The parts that change from version to version are the parts that need to be function parameters or array lookups.

Comment: Yes, the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle.  Minor note: I'd suggest making the experience array `static const`.

Comment: Thank You Mike. That was very helpful. I really appreciate your response.

Comment: @aschepler: You forgot to mention that you want to declare it `static` because you don't want code outside this module trying to access the array, and `const` because you aren't going to be changing its contents.

Comment: I was actually thinking of the meaning of `static` within a function: you can reuse this data every time the function is called.  I wouldn't use `static` at namespace scope in C++.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Personally, I'd put the array outside the function.  I'm not really a fan of `static` variables inside a function; they're like stealth globals.  (And I suffered some trauma years ago porting some code from Fortran to C++ that made heavy use of static locals...)  I prefer my globals (like my bugs) be as blatant as possible so I don't lose them.

Comment: If one wants to build the table directly from source: `grep "\- exp" file.cpp | sed "s/.*result=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/g" | awk '$1=$1' ORS=', '`.

Comment: A good thing about function statics is that, being *global* in some sense, they are *local* in others: you cannot access them outside of the scope of the function *unless* you give them away --like with any other private parts... and then the problem is not having it static, but giving them away. On the use of `static` at the namespace level, the same can be achieved with an unnamed namespace, but then again, is it worth? (g++ will complain about unused namespace static functions, but not about unused functions in anonymous namespaces..., so there is better diagnostics for the C version of it)

Comment: @jweyrich: +1 for parsing code to extract hard-coded data. @David: Another reason to avoid `static` in functions is that, like using globals, you can accidentally make your routine un-threadsafe. (Several Unix APIs used static buffers to return strings without `malloc()`).  This, of course, is not a problem if the `static` data is unchanging, like here, but it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

When you see a lot of "magic numbers" in repeated code, you should always ask yourself: Is there some way I can calculate that number?

It turns out that you can calculate the amount of experience needed for a certain level:

```
unsigned int experienceNeeded(unsigned int level) {
    float needed = 0;
    for(unsigned int x = 1; x < level; ++x) {
        needed += ::floor(static_cast<float>(x) + 300 * ::pow(2, static_cast<float>(x)/7));
    }
    return static_cast<unsigned int>(::floor(needed / 4));
}
```

This removes the need for the monolithic switch statement.

Comment: `return needed >> 2;` (For positive integers, shifting right is equivalent to division by a power of two and then flooring.) ^_-

Comment: Hey looking at your code I notice ++x? is this the same as x++? Hope you do not mind the millions of questions I have for everyone. I am here to learn.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone: For integers sure; certainly not for floats.

Comment: @USDblades: For primitive types such as `int`, it is the same. Differences arise when it is overloaded by a class. `x++` typically returns a copy of `x` then does incrementation, `++x` typically does the incrementation and returns itself (no copy is made).

Comment: oh ok. Thank You. I must head to bed. Have to head to work in 5 hours.

Comment: Technically, the difference between `++x` and `x++` is when the increment occurs.  `++x` immediately increments `x` and returns the new value.  `x++` returns the current value of `x` and then increments it. (To know *exactly* when the increment occurs, look up C++ "sequence points".) In the case of the third expression in a `for` statement, the expression's value isn't used so there's no difference.  In a loop like `while(*str) { char c = *str++; /* Do something with c */ }`, which loops through the characters in a null-terminated string, the postfix `++` is what you want.

Comment: Also, if `x` is a nonprimitive object, `x++` may perform worse than `++x` since `x++` may need to copy the current value of `x` into a temporary.  I think optimizers can catch this temporary and rearrange the operations a bit to eliminate it, but it's still recommended to use `++x` by default.

Answer (score 2):

the best two things you can do to learn to write good code are

1. Write stuff, and get peer reviewed.
2. Fix other people's broken stuff

you'll learn a lot with those two tasks.

Comment: I love the quick responses and how helpful everyone is.

Answer (score 1):

There is hardly a way without reading anything.

Language reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Bible: [http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-Special/dp/0201700735/ref=pd_sim_b_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201700735)

I like this one a lot but it's probably not the first step: [http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Specific-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0201924889](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889)

This is the unbelievable book but its content borders with insanity at some point :) [http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Design-Generic-Programming-Patterns/dp/0201704315/ref=pd_sim_b_6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)

Comment: Hey Schultz, I am using Cplusplus.com as a guideline right now. Ill check out some of the books you listed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I've done my best to interpret it.

With that in mind, learn the stl, and learn boost.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into open source code written by C++.
There are a lots of well designed project in source forge and other open source project site.
Download it and learn it from good source code.

Comment: There are also a lot of bad projects, too. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

No offence. But how about start from the 'function, array, loops' only if you don't know that stuff yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little conversion function that gets you close. It is a little off on the larger numbers. I don't know if its my function or a programming data leak. To use it just throw it in before the main function and after your library definitions and then you can use it!

```
int toExp(int level)
{
   double experience = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i < level; i++)
   {
      experience += (i / 4.0) + 75.0 * pow(2.0, (i / 7.0));
   }
   return floor(experience);
}
```

You will need to include the math library if you do end up using it. 
Here is a little example on how to use it:

```
int result = toExp(level) - currentExp;
cout << "Experience needed: " << result << endl
     << "Rune Essence: " << ceil(result/5.0) << endl
     << "Clay: " << ceil(result/5.0) << endl;
```

Again, the function does get of by 10 when it hits level 100 so its not the most accurate, but it is pretty short and simple.

Comment: I also just wanted to say that with ++i and i++ you can make your for loops even more tricky. If you put i++ as the third parameter than it will wait till the end of the loop to add one. If you put ++i then it will add one at the beginning of the for loop. There are not too many times you would have to worry about it, but occasionally it does make a difference.

Comment: @White_l2abbit: Do you care to share one circumstance where it would matter? I think that would help clarify your statement.